# Check which session variable is last modified

Tags: php, wordpress, session, last-modified

I store session variables (dates) in a file called datum.php

My datum.php file is like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION["chosen_date"] = $_POST['wapbk_hidden_date'];

?>
```

It works correct but the I want to echo one of them as `defaultDate` in my datepicker. Now it takes the first one like this in my `functions.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        numberOfMonths: [1,1],
        dayNamesMin: [ "Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za" ],
        monthNames: [ "Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December" ],
        minDate: 0,
        defaultDate: "<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION["chosen_date"]); ?>"
});
});
<?php
?>
```

I want to echo `chosen_date` or `datum_home` in `defaultDate` based on what variable is last modified.

Comment: Well then you have to check whether those session variables already contained the value you are trying to assign first - only if that was not the case, that value is to be considered changed. In that case, you can either write the date value itself into an additional session variable (like `$_SESSION["last_changed_date"]`), or the field name only, `$_SESSION["last_changed_field"] = "chosen_date"`, so that you can use that as index to access the correct session variable in your functions.php

Comment: Don’t forget that with both, you might need to provide a sensible default value, so that this doesn’t break if the user has changed neither date yet.

Comment: Sometimes it can happen that both variables has value. What code can I use to check last modified variable? Maybe you have a example?

Comment: Check if `$_SESSION["chosen_date"] == $_POST['wapbk_hidden_date']`, before you assign the value …

Comment: Hi I edited my code. Would go something like this?

Comment: No, not in that order. Right now, you are assigning the POST parameter value to the session variable first, and then you want to check if the two are the same or different afterwards … now guess what the outcome of that check of course will be every single time.

Comment: Hi something like this could work? See edit

Comment: No. Now you are checking whether the session variable is already identical with the POSTed value - only to then write that exact same value into the session variable _again_. Sorry, but you need to start approaching this with a little bit more logical thinking than you are doing so far.

Comment: Hi, my PHP knowledge is not that far so can't get any further than this I think

Comment: Hi, I added the same name to both form fields so on change one of them this variable is stored in the session variable. This works for me